Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
at nullthrows (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
at AssetGraph.getNodeIdByContentKey (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\graph\lib\ContentGraph.js:67:38)
at D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:82
at Array.map ()
at propagateSymbols (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:61)
at AssetGraphBuilder.build (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:174:62)
at async Object.run (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:62:37)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)
at async Object.run (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\requests\BundleGraphRequest.js:106:11)
at async RequestTracker.runRequest (D:\Local Disk\My-React\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:673:20)
i just add the icon and install the packages and suddenly this shows??

Perform the following steps:

Delete the existing .parcel-cache in the project

In the terminal, type npm cache clean --force

In the terminal, type npx parcel index.html


